# SQL Multiple filter and match

Tags: sql, filtering

```
|variety    |Markertype |ConnectID  |Data|
|-----------|-----------|-----------|----|
|variety 1  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 1  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 1  |BTYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 1  |CTYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 1  |DTYPE1     |1          |--  |
|variety 1  |ATYPE2     |2          |CC  |
|variety 1  |BTYPE2     |2          |CC  |
|variety 1  |CTYPE2     |2          |CC  |
|variety 2  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 2  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 2  |BTYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 3  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 3  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 3  |BTYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 4  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 5  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 5  |BTYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 5  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 5  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|NULL       |BTYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|NULL       |DTYPE1     |1          |--  |
|NULL       |ATYPE2     |2          |CC  |
|NULL       |BTYPE2     |2          |CC  |
|NULL       |CTYPE2     |2          |CC  |
|variety 6  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 6  |BTYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 7  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 7  |CTYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 8  |ATYPE1     |1          |AA  |
|variety 8  |DTYPE1     |1          |AA  |
```

From the above table I want to filter rows which are not NULL in column ' variety' and variety which has with same connect ID but should have ATYPE% and BTYPE% in markertype column

The code I am trying is

```
select variety, Markertype, ConnectID, Data
where variety is NOT NULL
AND Markertype = ATYPE%  OR BTYPE%;
```

But this not working;  I am expecting 16 cloumn data

```
variety 1,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 1,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 1,BTYPE1,1,AA
variety 1,ATYPE2,2,CC
variety 1,BTYPE2,2,CC
variety 2,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 2,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 2,BTYPE1,1,AA
variety 3,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 3,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 3,BTYPE1,1,AA
variety 5,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 5,BTYPE1,1,AA
variety 5,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 5,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 6,ATYPE1,1,AA
variety 6,BTYPE1,1,AA
```

Comment: Of course it's not working.  I don't see a `FROM` clause in your query.

Comment: sorry ! i didnt add complete query. The point here is how to filter the varieties which are having  'ATYPE%' and 'BTYPE%' with the same connect ID

Comment: What DBMS are you using? MySQL? SQL Server? Oracle? PostgreSQL? ...

Answer (score 0):

There are couple of issues in query.
You are missing `From Clause (from Table_Name)`(might be you missed to add complete query here).

Replace `=` with `Like` as `=` will look for exact same match.

```
select variety, Markertype, ConnectID, Data
from Table_Name tbl1
where variety is NOT NULL
AND Markertype Like  'ATYPE%'  OR tbl1.Markertype Like 'BTYPE%'
```

Comment: Thanks Nazir. I would like to filter only varieties having connect ID which should  have  'ATYPE%' and 'BTYPE%'

Comment: For Example, i wanted to filter-out variety 7 and variety 8 as they are not having both ATYPE% and BTYPE%

Answer (score 0):

One simple way:

```
select * 
from mytable a
where markertype like 'ATYPE%'
and exists 
(
  select * 
  from mytable b
  where b.markertype like 'BTYPE%'
  and b.variety = a.variety
  and b.connectid = a.connectid
)
union all
select * 
from mytable b
where markertype like 'BTYPE%'
and exists 
(
  select * 
  from mytable a
  where a.markertype like 'ATYPE%'
  and a.variety = b.variety
  and a.connectid = b.connectid
);
```

Or with aggregation:

```
select * 
from mytable a
where (markertype like 'ATYPE%' or markertype like 'BTYPE%')
and (variety, connectid) in
(
  select variety, connectid
  from mytable
  group by variety, connectid
  having count(case when markertype like 'ATYPE%' then 1 end) > 0
     and count(case when markertype like 'BTYPE%' then 1 end) > 0
);
```

Answer (score 0):

Make sure you follow right syntax of `SELECT`  statement. Be careful with brackets when you write `AND` and `OR` together.

Try this

```
SELECT variety, Markertype, ConnectID, Data
  FROM TableName
WHERE variety is NOT NULL AND 
   (Markertype Like  'ATYPE_'  OR Markertype Like 'BTYPE_')
```

OR

```
SELECT variety, Markertype, ConnectID, Data
  FROM TableName
WHERE variety !='' AND 
   (Markertype Like  'ATYPE_'  OR Markertype Like 'BTYPE_')
```

Answer (score 0):

If I hadn't misunderstood your requirements, the following query would return what you expect:

```
WITH CTE AS (
SELECT DISTINCT T1.VARIETY, T2.CONNECTID FROM (SELECT variety, ConnectID   FROM myTable  WHERE  variety is not null and Markertype like  'ATYPE%') AS T1 
INNER JOIN (SELECT variety, ConnectID   FROM myTable     WHERE  variety is not null and Markertype like  'BTYPE%') AS T2 ON T1.ConnectID = T2.ConnectID AND T1.variety = T2.variety  )

SELECT  T.* FROM CTE INNER JOIN myTable  AS T ON CTE.ConnectID = T.ConnectID AND CTE.variety = T.variety WHERE  (Markertype like  'BTYPE%' OR Markertype like  'ATYPE%')
```

This would return the *17* rows you displayed but please note that you said

> I am expecting 16 cloumn data

Hope it helps.